# How to create a class diagram in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Please tell me how to create a class diagram in Android Studio. I want to create a class diagram from all Kotlin packages in Android Studio. Since the structure of the code is more complex, I need a way to automatically create the specified diagram. In the search I found 2 plugins with which you can build a diagram, but both do not work (PlantUML is outdated, and CodeIris does not add my objects to the diagram)

What are the ways to create charts in Android Studio at the moment?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q4pf.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Solution `build-in` diagram tool for older versions of Android Studio  :***

---

1. Open `Android Studio`.
2. -> `Project` and select the `package` you want a diagram for.
3. -> `Diagrams`.
4. -> `Show Diagram` to create `Class Diagram`.

Check also [Astah](https://astahblog.com/2012/01/12/template-for-android/), [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/getting-started-in-lucidchart), [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide.jsp), [simpleUMLCE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4946-simpleumlce), [PlantUML](https://readthedocs.org/projects/plantuml-documentation/)

---

[**`ObjectAid UML Explorer`**](https://github.com/CagataySonmez/Android-for-Beginners/blob/master/README.md)[(check this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385047/eclipse-plug-in-objectaid-uml-explorer-class-diagram-export-in-higher-resoluti).

Once installed from Android Studio Plugins you can access **->** **`New`** **->** **`Class Diagram`**.

---

[**`PlantUML`**](https://readthedocs.org/projects/plantuml-documentation/)

1. Install `PlantUML` from [plugin repo](https://plantuml.com/running).
2. Select the `package` / `class` to create the `Diagram`.
3. Create **New File**.
4. Paste the `path` and add `PlantUML` syntax.
5. Save File with `.puml` & `.txt` extension.
6. Nav to the directory.
7. You should handle the `Terminal` usually through `plantuml nameOfYourFile.puml`
8. And `PlantUML` should generate the diagram.

***You should repeat this for every `package` in your project.***

---

[**`Visual Paradigm`**](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide.jsp)

1. Install `Visual Paradigm`, [check this](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/community.jsp).
2. Select `File`->`New`->`Project`.
3. Select `Empty Project`->`Next`.
4. Click `Finish`.
5. Then `Import` the `Java Sources`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "Diagrams" button. I attached a screenshot with the menu to the problem description at the top

Comment: I just edited the post.